# How to make same actions on Multiple links using selenium with c#

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium

I am automating our portal where I want the same actions to happen on multiple sim pages. I want to write a method that will import and open these URLs, that I can obtain in a CSV and perform the same actions on them all. Locators of these pages are the same so trigger actions are not a problem. the problem is creating a method that will import the links from CSV and perform actions on them in each iteration.

driver.Url = TestContext.DataRow[0.ToString()]; but DataRow returned error

Error   CS0012  The type 'DataRow' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

Comment: could be as simple as creating a function that takes the URL...  you should include more code in your post.  Are you using a library to read the csv?

Comment: I am very new to selenium. The libraries I am using is 

using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.V106.HeadlessExperimental;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Contexts;
using System.Security.Policy;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

Comment: I would check for something in VS's package manager...  a search for "CSV" should bring up some candidates.  Your question might be too broad... but if you include some code trials maybe someone can give you a good answer.